# Stripe Connect API Update PaymentIntent

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe connect in my API, I would like to update an existing paymentIntent.  The official Library for the API Provides these methods.

```
public PaymentIntent Get(string paymentIntentId, 
    PaymentIntentGetOptions options = null, RequestOptions requestOptions = null)
public PaymentIntent Update(string paymentIntentId, 
    PaymentIntentUpdateOptions options, RequestOptions requestOptions = null);
```

The only thing I would like to update on the resource is the destination so I started to do so before I realize there is no easy way:

```
var paymentIntentService = new PaymentIntentService();
var paymentIntent = paymentIntentService.Get(transaction.ExternalTransactionId);

if (null != destinationStripeAccount)
{
    paymentIntent.TransferData.DestinationId = destinationStripeAccount.AccountId;
}

//This takes in a PaymentIntentUpdateOptions instead of a paymentIntent WTF
paymentIntentService.Update(paymentIntent.Id, new PaymentIntentUpdateOptions {  });
```

The PaymentIntent is not a PaymentIntentUpdate Options, so I need to map all of the Values to the other. I would prefer not to need to install an additional dependency like AutoMapper, and mapping the fields manually would be a hassle.

Does anyone know if there is a way to just Update the Destination, or of a simple way to update a payment intent?

Comment: Don't you only need to provide what needs to be changed in the update options object?

Comment: I'll see if I can find the source code for that object and confirm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since according to the documentation, the majority of the members are optional, I believe you only need to provide what needs to be changed/updated to the options object.

```
var paymentIntentService = new PaymentIntentService();
var paymentIntent = paymentIntentService.Get(transaction.ExternalTransactionId);

if (null != destinationStripeAccount) {
    var options = new PaymentIntentUpdateOptions() {
        TransferData = new PaymentIntentTransferDataOptions {
            Destination = destinationStripeAccount.AccountId
        }
    };
    paymentIntentService.Update(paymentIntent.Id, options);
}
```

Reference [PaymentIntentUpdateOptions.TransferData (GitHub)](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Services/PaymentIntents/PaymentIntentUpdateOptions.cs#L124)

Comment: Hmm, Interesting, I didn't think of how the behavior would be when the model is optional.  I just assumed by optional they meant if the field was omitted the state would be cleared.  I'll need to investigate

Comment: I've confirmed with the stripe team this is the case.  I'm a bit confused on how they handle the case where you explicitly want to null an optional value, but this makes the my code a lot simpler